# How can I access this old Realtek card reader?

Tags: 14.04, drivers, usb, realtek, phone

I think I need drivers for this cell-phone device plug by usb. The system can't see any partition.  Also, it looks like the links for Linux Realtek drivers are broken.

I would like to mount (access) the device.

```
$ sudo lsusb -vd 0bda:0111 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:0111 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Card Reader
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x0bda Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
  idProduct          0x0111 Card Reader
  bcdDevice           11.22
  iManufacturer           1 Generic
  iProduct                2 USB2.0-CRW
  iSerial                 3 20021111153705700
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           32
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          4 CARD READER
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              500mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass         8 Mass Storage
      bInterfaceSubClass      6 SCSI
      bInterfaceProtocol     80 Bulk-Only
      iInterface              5 Bulk-In, Bulk-Out, Interface
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x82  EP 2 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0200  1x 512 bytes
        bInterval               0
Device Qualifier (for other device speed):
  bLength                10
  bDescriptorType         6
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  bNumConfigurations      1
Device Status:     0x0000
  (Bus Powered)
```

Comment: See my edit above.

Comment: That's much better. :-) Could you please plug a memory card into the card reader, wait about 10 seconds, then run `sudo dmesg | tail -n 50` and `sudo lsblk -f` and [edit] your question to include both of their output? It would help if you use a memory card that is known to work in other card readers. You can also test the card reader in question on other USB ports or other computers. Thanks.

Comment: [Debian bug report #576861](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=576861) suggests that the card reader works fundamentally but that it may fail to notify the computer of (dis-)connection events. The work-around would be quite different though because the HAL subsystem was replaced by Udev since the bug report. Heavily related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/102377/47852

Comment: I can't insert a micro sd card, the phone work fine but the joint for the micro sd  is broken.

Comment: Are you saying you don't have a suitable memory card handy to test the card reader? As long as that's the case it's going to be very difficult or even impossible to answer your question accurately.